# WebPack Externals: How is the regex option's dependency "found" for UMD library targets?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vtk, webpack-4, vtk.js

WebPack provides a handy way to externalize dependencies. This can be nice if you would like the consuming application to furnish this dependency.

In my situation, I am targeting UMD output, and I use the `object` external syntax for most external dependencies, and string for a few others:

- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#object
- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#string

However, I have one dependency that recommends the following usage:

```js
import vtkGenericRenderWindow from 'vtk.js/Sources/Rendering/Misc/GenericRenderWindow';
import vtkWidgetManager from 'vtk.js/Sources/Widgets/Core/WidgetManager';
import vtkVolume from 'vtk.js/Sources/Rendering/Core/Volume';
import vtkVolumeMapper from 'vtk.js/Sources/Rendering/Core/VolumeMapper';
import vtkInteractorStyleMPRSlice from 'vtk.js/Sources/Interaction/Style/InteractorStyleMPRSlice';
import vtkPaintFilter from 'vtk.js/Sources/Filters/General/PaintFilter';
```

This butts up against the limitation outlined in the "Authoring Libraries" Guide:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#external-limitations

And requires the `regex` option to work.

**When using the `regex` option to externalize, how does WebPack know where/how to link up the dependency my parent application provides to the code that matches the `regex` pattern?**

Helpful:

- [vtk.js source browser](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#external-limitations)
- [vtk.js es6 usage guide](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/docs/intro_vtk_as_es6_dependency.html#Application)